# Do giant rings still appear after collecting all 7 Chaos Emeralds?

Tags: sonic-mania

[According to Polygon](https://www.polygon.com/2017/8/18/16169566/sonic-mania-giant-ring-locations), Sonic Mania has *at least* 32 giant rings hidden throughout the game's 12 zones. A skilled player could collect all 7 emeralds before even finishing Studiopolis Zone.

What would happen if I found a giant ring after collecting all 7 Chaos Emeralds?

Would the remaining giant rings still appear? Or would they all despawn after every emerald had been collected?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they still appear.

Collecting a giant ring gives you 50 rings, which incidentally is what you need to become Super.

[image: Sonic]

This is also how it worked in *Sonic 3* and *Sonic and Knuckles*.